# Выборка из 3-х таблиц в одну

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня есть три таблицы(поля):
questions(id, question)
answers(id,answer)
questions-answers(result_id, question,answer)
нужно сделать выборку из 3-х таблиц и поместить все в один со структурой, как в коде.
Укажите, пожалуйста на ошибки! Заранее спасибо.

```
SELECT t1.result_id, t1.question AS q_num, t1.answer AS a_num, t2.id AS q_id, t2.question, t3.id AS a_id, t3.answer FROM questions_answers AS t1, questions AS t2, answers AS t3 LEFT JOIN t2 LEFT JOIN t3
```

Comment: а где код-то? :)

Comment: @DmitryV., прошу прощения, вроде вставлял)

Comment: что не работает то?

Comment: @Suvitruf, Запрос не работает. Иначе зачем бы я спрашивал!

Comment: @DaVinchi какая ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы условия для `LEFT JOIN` не написали.
Не знаю, что у вас в таблице questions-answers обозначают question, answer. Предполагаю, что это внешние ключи на таблицы questions и answers. Тогда так:

```
SELECT t1.result_id, t1.question AS q_num, t1.answer AS a_num, 
       t2.id AS q_id, t2.question, 
       t3.id AS a_id, t3.answer 
   FROM questions_answers AS t1
   LEFT JOIN questions AS t2 ON t1.question = t2.id
   LEFT JOIN answers AS t3 ON  t1.answer = t3.id
```

Comment: А разве не нужно обозначать, что выборка из всех трех таблиц???   
`SELECT t1.result_id, t1.question AS q_num, t1.answer AS a_num, 
  t2.id AS q_id, t2.question, t3.id AS a_id, t3.answer    
  
FROM questions_answers AS t1, questions AS t2, answers AS t3 `   
- это 3 разные таблицы( questions_answers, questions, answers)

Comment: @DaVinchi не нужно http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx

Comment: А можно без указания условий просто объединить  выбранные столбцы, переименовав некоторые, чтобы различать??

Comment: @DaVinchi нет, вы должны указать по каким столбцам объединять

Comment: Спасибо большое, постараюсь лучше разобраться. Вы очень помогли. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @DaVinchi не за что. Сайт для того  существует )